# Storyboardから設置したUIViewでAVPlayerの動画を再生

Tags: swift, xcode

[Swift2]Storyboardから設置したUIViewでAVPlayerの動画を再生する方法
http://bick.xyz/archives/586

を参考にUIViewでAVPlayerを再生したいです。

Storyboardに貼り付けたUIviewから、AVPlayerViewのインスタンスにして
`@IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: AVPlayerView!`
に接続すると以下のエラーが発生します。（この行で）

> 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type '<<<\error type>>'
>   Use of undeclared type 'AVPlayerView'

これはどのような対応をすれば解決するのでしょうか？

- XCode 7.1
- DeploymentTarget: 9.1

です。

Comment: フレームワークのインポート`import AVKit`が抜けているのではないかと、思われます。ご確認ください。

Comment: import AVKitを入れてみましたが、「<パス>: Use of undeclared type 'AVPlayerView'」は変わりません。

Comment: 質問者さんの新規の質問で事情がわかりましたが、`AVPlayerView`は、`AVKit`で定義されているので、プログラマの独自のクラス名とするのは不適当です。その点は置いておくとして、クラス`AVPlayerView`の定義がじゅうぶんでないため、未定義（undeclared）というメッセージになっているものと考えられます。